# Delete Service when GKE Ingress is stilling linking

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have a GKE ingress and 3 backend services linking to it. Then I found I couldn't delete any service because of the linking I suppose. Is it possible to temporarily disable the ingress? Because sometime during the deployment, I have to remove the service and then install the service again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As per this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#removing_the_configuration_specified_in_a_frontendconfig_or_backendconfig), to disable the GKE ingress, you can modify
  the ingress resource and set the enabled field to false. This can be
  done using the kubectl command-line tool command : `kubectl edit ingress <ingress-name>`  or by modifying the YAML configuration file
  for the ingress resource.

> The following BackendConfig manifest disables the nginx ingress :
>
> ```
> apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
> kind: BackendConfig
> metadata:
>   name: my-backendconfig
> spec:
>   ingress:
>     enabled: false
>   securityPolicy:
>     name: " "
> ```

- As per this [Blog](https://bobcares.com/blog/kubernetes-disable-ingress/#:%7E:text=Sometimes%20we%20need%20to%20disable,can%20disable%20the%20Kubernetes%20Ingress.) by Shahalamol, A boolean value can be set to
  enable or disable the service which helps in disabling the ingress.
  You can follow the example given in this blog .

> ```
> ingress:
> default_backend: false
> ```